# Nonlinear Differential equation in NDSolve encountering a 1/0

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, warning-messages

I have nonlinear differential equation that I am trying to get `NDSolve` to figure out for me. My code is:

```
NDSolve[{1/r^2 D[r^2 D[p[r], r], r] + p[r]^(3/2) == 0, 
  Derivative[1][p][0] == 10^-12, p[0] == 1}, p[r], {r, 0, 100}]
```

It is self contained. The first initial condition is supposed to be == 0 but I got rid of one of the infinity errors by setting it to `10^-12`. Beyond that, I am still getting

```
"Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0. encountered. "
```

and

```
"NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at r == 0."
```

Edit*: I've change the equation to something a little better after working through some of the math. I'm still getting the same problem. 
For some context, this equation is a particular example of the Lane-Emden Equation.

Comment: I've changed the problem a little bit (gotten rid of m and beta). Still the same problem, despite this being a know form of a DE.

Answer (score 6):

We can start with the series solution about `r == 0`, in order to find the value of `p''[0]`:

```
ode = 1/r^2 D[r^2 D[p[r], r], r] + p[r]^(3/2);  (* to be set equal to 0 *)

(* derivatives of p up to the 12th order - do not need to go so high *)
pcoeffs = 
  Module[{n = -1}, 
   Nest[Join[#, 
      First@Solve[
        SeriesCoefficient[ode, {r, 0, n++}] == 0 /. #]] &, {p[0] -> 
      1}, 12]
   ];
pval[x_] :=   (* the local series solution, up to the order in pcoeffs *)
 Total@Table[Derivative[n][p][0] x^n/n!, {n, 0, Length@pcoeffs - 1}] /. pcoeffs
```

We'll use the value of `p''[0]` to form a new ODE that does not have a division by zero problem at `r == 0`.

```
pval''[0]
(*  -(1/3)  *)

p2 = First@Solve[ode == 0, p''[r]]
(*  {p''[r] -> (-r p[r]^(3/2) - 2 Derivative[1][p][r])/r}  *)
```

Construct a new ODE with `Piecewise`, with a special case for `r == 0`:

```
newode = p''[r] == Piecewise[{{p''[r] /. p2, r > 0}}, pval''[0]];
{sol} = NDSolve[{newode, Derivative[1][p][0] == 0, p[0] == 1}, 
   p, {r, 0, 100}];
```

The solution becomes complex when `p[r]` becomes negative.
Here is what the solution looks like:

```
Plot[ReIm@p[r] /. sol // Evaluate, {r, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

**An alternative**

One might even use the local series for an initial segment.  For instance, up to `r == 0.1`, the local series is well within machine precision accuracy:

```
Last@pval[r]
% /. r -> 0.1
(*
  (2719 r^12)/53374464000
  5.0942*10^-20
*)
```

(Keep in mind that the series is an even-powered, alternating series, apparently with decreasing terms for small `r`. So that the error is bounded by the last term.)

```
newode = p''[r] == Piecewise[{{p''[r] /. p2, r > 0.1}}, pval''[r]];
{sol} = NDSolve[{newode, Derivative[1][p][0] == 0, p[0] == 1}, 
   p, {r, 0, 100}];

(* Plot is the same as above *)
```

Comment: I must made a mistake because my solution for p(r) does not look like yours. Will look and see where my error is :)

Comment: Actually when I plot your solution from 0..4 I get same as what you have (zoom in). (the blue line, which I assume is p(r) !  I can't get solution for more than t=4 seconds.

Comment: @Nasser Around `r == 4`, the solution becomes complex (due to the `3/2` power). Hence the `ReIm[p[r]]`.  Is that the problem?

Comment: Oh, I did not know this, I thought that NDSolve needed more accuracy or something like this at t=4 and it stopped. But I think your solution is the more mathematically correct way to do it.

Comment: Yeah, the starting-away-from-zero trick always bothers me, but then I'm a mathematician.  In this case, the value of `p[$MachineEpsilon]` ***should be*** `1.`, to machine precision, since `p[r] == 1 - x^2/6 + x^4/80 +...` rounds to `1.` at `r = $MachineEpsilon`.  So your method is, theoretically, as accurate as possible. OTOH, I worry about the numerics of dividing by `$MachineEpsilon` (to get `p''[r]`).

Answer (score 6):

I like to convert everything to first order (sometimes can be useful for use with state space and non-linear state space functions). But this works:

```
eps = $MachineEpsilon;
eq1 = x1'[t] == x2[t];
eq2 = x2'[t] == -2/t x2[t] - x1[t]^(3/2);
ic = {x1[eps] == 1, x2[eps] == 0};
s = NDSolve[{eq1, eq2, ic}, {x1, x2}, {t, eps, 4}];


Plot[Evaluate[x1[t] /. s], {t, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True,
    FrameLabel -> {{"p(r)", None}, {"r", "Numerical solution"}},BaseStyle -> 14]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 Plot[Evaluate[x2[t] /. s], {t, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True,
    FrameLabel -> {{"p'(r)", None}, {"r", "Numerical solution"}},BaseStyle -> 14]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Sorry about the edit.  Somehow I thought I was editing mine!! :)

Comment: Just a side note: in this case converting the equation to 1st order isn't necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Another method that avoids both the divide-by-zero and the starting-away-from-zero is to use an `If`.  Here we use `q[r]` as `p'[r]`.

```
n = 3/2; rmax = 100;
soln = NDSolve[{p'[r] == q[r], 
     q'[r] == -p[r]^n - q[r] If[r > 0, 2/r, 0], p[0] == 1, 
     q[0] == 0}, {p, q}, {r, 0, rmax}] // Flatten;
Plot[Re@Evaluate[p[r] /. soln], {r, 0, rmax},
 GridLines -> Automatic, Frame -> True,
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-1/2, 1}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Your `If` and my `Piecewise` basically do similar things.  But yours is targeted to the term that is divided by zero. (+1) -- BTW, it used to be the case that `Piecewise` was a better choice (AFAIR), but nowadays `NDSolve` either applies `PiecewiseExpand` to the `If`, or treats `If` in the way it treats `Piecewise`. (In general `Piecewise` is the choice for constructing functions and equations, and `If` is for programming. But that distinction has become less clear in recent versions.)

Answer (score 2):

One more approach. One can regularize the equation as follows:

```
e = 0.0000001;
ndsl = NDSolveValue[{1/(r + e)^2 D[(r + e)^2* D[p[r], r], r] + 
      p[r]^(3/2) == 0, Derivative[1][p][0] == 0, p[0] == 1}, 
   p[r], {r, 0, 100}];
```

where e is a regularization constant. Then

```
Plot[Re@Evaluate[ndsl], {r, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> All]
```

yields

[image]

Looking (at least, by eye) quite like in the answers of MichaelE2 and LouisB. One may play with e and see that starting from some value, the answer is weakly dependent on it. So, it is just one more approach.